# Repeatative search flow

Tags: usability, mobile, search, mobile-application, search-suggestion

For my mobile application, I am planing to change current flow as I don't think it has good UX. 
In this app there are more than 10 categories each has some specific meaning and  specific database where user can put search term and get the results.

How can it fit into good user experience as current screen has repetitive action flow: Click the category --> enter keyword in search box --> get the search results(mostly in table format)

[image: Home screen]
[image: Search screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Amazon has something which would be of interest:

[image]

Comment: This is great idea, but what if some of category search available on paid subscription?

Comment: @Bharat I would recommend controlling it server-side

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for can be achieved by [Filtered and/or Faceted Search](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/filters-vs-facets/).

Basically, you use these filters to narrow the scope of the search, guiding the user through the search process and clearing iterative actions. For example, in your app:

[image]

You can see some great examples, guidelines and *"how to's"* [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/navigation/design-better-faceted-navigation-your-websites-41411437)